Identify this 70s-80s non-lego brick brand, hollow studs, beams in the underside of bricks
Yesterday my brother had a sudden urge to call me and ask about one of our childhood lego-like game set, it had multiple things in it's manual, one was a windmill, a car, and if we remember correctly a human. These bricks had holes, and were softer than LEGO bricks. We don't have them anymore but my bro wants to buy these somewhere, but we don't know the brand and couldn't find anything on them.
Sadly we only found this image:

Any idea or help is greatly appreciated!

I see that's a stock image. Could you locate some actual bricks and take a couple of close-up photos? Sometimes there are logos or details that help identification.

Hello! Sadly we don't have any piece anymore and only could find this image. I could be wrong, but as I remember, these didn't had any logo on them, the sides were smooth, and all of the pieces had holes in them.
Plus info, if you put together two thinner 2x4 pieces (for example the red and grey ones in the middle of the picture), they had holes on the side, you could easily take them apart with a toothpick.

Looks somewhat like Rasti bricks, minus the groove you mentioned. I can't find any information on whether there were grooved variants of that brick. They were known to have very good interlocking and needing a separate tool to disconnect the bricks though.

YES! This is it, thank you so much! I remember now after searching for some images that the grooved ones were made to hold wheels. You made our day.
